# How to get sub-items of a nav menu for current page?

Tags: jquery, html

Suppose that we have a navigation menu called "Top Menu" like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1
    <ul>
      <li>Sub Item 1-1</li>
    </ul>
    
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3
     <ul>
        <li>Sub Item 3-1</li>
        <li>Sub Item 3-2</li>
     </ul>
  </li>

  <li>Item 4
     <ul>
        <li>Sub Item 4-1</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 5
    <ul>
       <li>Sub Item 5-1</li>
       <li>Sub Item 5-2</li>
       <li>Sub Item 5-3</li>
    </ul> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

For example, When someone is visiting Item 3's page, I want to show him Item 3's Sub Items links on an un-ordered list in the page content (in article section). Is it possible to do such a thing?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, Please clarify your specific problem

Comment: @Pedram I've edited the question.

Comment: Everything is possible, but you should try something and if you faced with problem, ask here. almost no one write code for you.